# Comparing arrays in chai

Tags: arrays, node.js, chai

I'm writing some tests with chai and chai-as-promised (and more frameworks, but it doesn't matter in this case) and I need to check if array I get from a web-page is same as a predefined array. I tried to use `expect(arrayFromPage).to.eventually.deep.equal(predefinedArray)`, but it won't work, because order of elements on page is sometimes different (which is OK, I don't need to check if they are in the same order).

I've found a way to workaround the issue by using `expect(listFromPage).to.eventually.include.all.members(predefinedArray)`, but I'd like to know if there is a better solution.

What bothers me most in my workaround, is that I only assure that `predefinedArray` is subset of `listFromPage`, not that they are made of same elements.

So, I'd like to know if there is an assert that will pass for `[1,2,3]` and `[3,2,1]`, but not for `[1]` and `[1,2,3]` or `[1,2,3,4]` and `[1,2,3]`.

I know that I can use some second expectation (compare lengths, or something else), but I'd like to know if there is a one-line solution.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Seeing as this was marked as resolved earlier, I tried doing the same thing as in the accepted answer. It probably worked back then, but doesn't seem to work anymore:

```js
expect([1, 2, 3, 4]).to.have.all.members([2, 4, 3, 1]);
```

Gives the following error:

```
AssertionError: expected 1 to be an array
```

I did a little more research and found a pull request that added this functionality back in 2013:

https://github.com/chaijs/chai/pull/153

So the official way of doing this now is like this:

```js
expect([1, 2, 3, 4]).to.have.same.members([2, 4, 3, 1]);
```

For completeness, here's the error that two different sets produces:

```
AssertionError: expected [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ] to have the same members as [ 4, 3, 1 ]
```

Hope this helps anyone searching for the same answer now. :-)

Comment: Any ideas why it worked in August '16 if this pull-request was merged in '13?

Comment: Nope. But if we dig deep in the commits, then perhaps they made it not work because it never was supposed to some time between then and now. :-)

Comment: If you ever test an array of objects this might by your solution: `expect(result).to.have.same.deep.members(expected);`

Comment: If the order is relevant you can use [`to.have.ordered.members`](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_ordered)

Answer (score 5):

It's not entirely clear from the documentation, but `.to.have.all.members` seems to work. I could only find a mention of this feature for [`.keys`](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_keys), but looks like it also works for `.members` with arrays.

Comment: Do you mean that `expect([1,2,3,4]).to.have.all.members([1,2,3])` will fail? Because I need it to fail in this case and it is the main concern about using `to.have.all.members`

Comment: Yes, exactly: `expect([1, 2, 3, 4]).to.have.all.members([2, 3, 1, 4])` succeeds, but `expect([1, 2, 3, 4]).to.have.all.members([1, 2, 3])` fails with `AssertionError: expected [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ] to have the same members as [ 1, 2, 3 ]`

Comment: This probably worked at the time you wrote it, but has since stopped working. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42972555/664955) for a current working example. :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with 2 lines :

```
expect(listFromPage).to.eventually.include.all.members(predefinedArray)
expect(predefinedArray).to.eventually.include.all.members(listFromPage)
```

With this, you'll check if both arrays contains the same values. But order does not matter.

Comment: I'm not sure If it works, as `listFromPage` is array of promises, and `predefinedArray` is array of values. I could though compare lengths of the arrays, but I wonder if there is a one-line solution.

Comment: There is a one line solution using "have", as described in the other answer.

Answer (score 2):

From the future, the way that worked for me, was to use **.deepEqual** which did the trick for me

```
assert.deepEqual(['name'], ['name'], 'this must be same to proceed');
```

Comment: OP was looking for a non order dependent way to do it, deep equal seems to expect the order to be the same :(

Answer (score 2):

`.members` seems to be the way to do this now.

Specifically:
`have.members`
and
`have.deep.members`

depending on your needs.

https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_members